# Create a Procfile to declare the command to launch the web process:

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have created a Procfile file, however I keep getting the following.

```
(venv)Micheles-MacBook-Pro:bed4ted michele$ foreman start/usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/procfile.rb:31:in `read': Is a directory - Procfile (Errno::EISDIR)
from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/procfile.rb:31:in `parse_procfile'
from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/procfile.rb:17:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:24:in `new'
from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:24:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:81:in `new'
from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:81:in `engine'
from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:33:in `start'
from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /usr/bin/foreman:15
```

I may be making a completely junior mistake, but I cannot see it at all. I've checked other questions that have been posted on stackoverflow, but I am still at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python, make sure you're using the cedar stack.
second, the procfile must be named "Procfile", not "procfile" or "Procfile.rb" and it must be in the root of your project (next to requirements.txt)

Hopefully that should get you 90% of the way there.

Comment: I cross checked to make sure (1) I was using the cedar stack, (2) that my "Procfile" was named and in the correct place, but I'm still getting the same result. Any other ideas, Jody?

Comment: not off hand.  perhaps post the contents of the Procfile.  Also, does the procfile work when you push to heroku? or are you only having issues locally?

Comment: Jody, this is what I have in my Procfile.
`python hellodjango/manage.py run_gunicorn -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" -w 3`

Comment: not sure - don't have access to my work machine at the moment. Try consulting this article which has some good info about gunicorn and heroku - http://www.askthepony.com/blog/2011/07/getting-django-on-heroku-prancing-8-times-faster/  Also, make sure you have "web" at tehe front of your procfile.  It also may be worth it to try to get django running with simply ....manage.py run_server instead of gunicorn, just to simplify.

Comment: Thanks, Jody. I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: For the record, here is our procfile python project/manage.py run_gunicorn --workers=3 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT

Comment: Do you not need to begin the `Procfile` with the dyno type (`web:` for this), so you'd have `web: python hellodjango/manage.py run_gunicorn -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" -w 3`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like foreman is getting confused while trying to parse your Procfile. What output do you get when you run `foreman check`?

Based on one of your comments this may be an issue with the formatting of your Procfile line. Foreman expects every process in a Procfile to be in the format `name:command` ([see the manual](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/#PROCFILE)). Does your Procfile line start with the text `web:` or some other name? If not try adding that.

Also, what command are you using to run this? `foreman run`?